# Can I follow that a sequence $a_{3n}$ converges, if $a_{2n}$ is monotone and $a_{2n+1}$ converges?!

Tags: real-analysis

I would say no, because I don't know if $a_{2n}$ bounded is or not. But Can anyone help me to find an example?!

Comment: $a_{3^{n}}$ is  subsequence of $a_{2n+1}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: The subsequence $a_{3n}$ may not converge. Take, for example, $a_n = (-1)^n.$ However if you are interested to $a_{3^n},$ then it converges, as said above by Kabo Murphy.

Comment: The sequence $0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,\cdots$ is a simple counterexample.